# Jquery validation error and success placement

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery validation. I want error and success placement near to each field.

Problem is once success encountered, control is not going to error placement block. Help me to implement error and success message placement

Comment: I'm trying last one week... Problem is creating different div for error and success... I'm using dynamic div creation

Comment: I'm using proper errorClass and ValidClass methods also.... Implemented highlight and Un highlight

Comment: Show some code or create a problem **jsfiddle**